# Laravel Streamed Response From Azure (Multiple Files)

Tags: php, laravel, azure, pdf, laravel-storage

I've been working on this setup but I cannot save the downloaded streamed response to my zip file. I am using ZipArchive package and currently when I use return on the one with the yellow arrow. It returns the correct pdf but when I try to put it in the zip folder. It doesn't recognize it as a pdf file and return null. I need to save multiple pdf file in the add Zip File but right now I'm trying with only one pdf for now.
[image]

Comment: please include your code as text rather than an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. What I did is convert it to a raw pdf file and read it using AddFromString.

[image: Solution]